# Select2 Multiselect Dropdown custom search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, multi-select

I am trying to modify a select2 multiselect dropdown's search functionality in the way that instead of searching for the elements which contains the searched character I want to search for elements which starts with the searched character. I have referred to the select2 documentation but they have stated that -

> For multi-select boxes, there is no distinct search control

So does that mean that we do not have any workaround to modify that functionality?

Example for my requirement:
Assuming the dropdown contains 4 elements viz,

> Australia,Argentina,India,United States

and if user types 'A' for searching it returns all four values since all the values has 'A' in it. But my requirement is to return only the values starting with 'A' like

> Australia and Argentina

How can this be achieved?

Comment: *For multi-select boxes, there is no distinct search control* refers to hiding the search control. If you don't want to hide it you can ignore that sentence

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I will do it for sure But I have to have it tested by adding some more select tags with different start characters.

Comment: Keep me updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `matcher` property by requiring it to modify the search action using

```
select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], ...)
```

Please note that this property only exists in the full version of `select2` (`select2.full.js`)

```js
function search(term, text) {
  if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    return true;
  }
 
  return false;
}
 
$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (f) {
  $("select").select2({
    matcher: f(search)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select multiple style="width:100%;">
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Family</option>
  <option>Freezone</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nx1eaLgz/

Comment: But this is a single select. What I was asking was related to multiselect dropdown

Comment: Try `<select mutliple>`  then

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I know it was just for single select, I thought that it would be easy for you to add a multiple :) Answer updated

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy if I am using select2.min.js, will this work? or for select2.min.js is there any other way to achieve?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt you need the full version of select2 unfortunately if you want your requirement. The simple version of select2 contains only the basic functions, when you get deeper into the functionalities you'll need the full one.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy can you please convert your snippet to a fiddle?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt sure, answer updated with a fiddle link!

Comment: It really worked eventhough I had to do some customising.+1 for recommending the answer